# Wireshark - how to merge partial content data of PDF file

Tags: wireshark, wireless, wireshark-dissector

Basically, the title is the questions itself. I've scanned the network and catch the partial content of PDF files, some files which are small can be saved as a whole piece and exported, but some files are divided on separate packets. How can I merge those packets and export PDF file ?

Comment: What protocol was used to transfer the PDF file?  Was it HTTP or something else?

Comment: Http and wireshark shows it as a partial content

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark offers an *"Export Objects"* feature, described in [Section 5.7.8 of the Wireshark User Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html#ChIOExportObjectsDialog).

For it to work, Wireshark must have captured all the packets that contain the data that comprises the object (the PDF in this case) so that the object can be reassembled, and you must have enabled the TCP preference that allows subdissectors (the HTTP dissector in this case) to reassemble TCP streams.  That preference is enabled via `Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> TCP -> Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams`.